# ZF2 I18n error with PHPUnit

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-framework2

I am using Zend\I18n\Validator\Alnum in one of my modules.  When I execute it as a full MVC application through the browser, it works fine.  When I execute it with PHPUnit though, it throws the following error:

> Zend\I18n\Exception\ExtensionNotLoadedException: Zend\I18n\Filter
>   component requires the intl PHP extension

Why is this so?

I am using PHP V 5.5, so as far as I know, the intl extension is automatically enabled.  Neither my apache2\php.ini or cli\php.ini had a default locale set.  Nevertheless, I tried enabling it in the cli\php.ini but this made no difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you enabled it in the correct php.ini? Did you try a quick `phpinfo()` from inside a test?

Comment: Thanks Jon.  That was a good idea.  It seems the extension is not loading correctly.  Furthermore, apt-get can't install it - says my packages are broken!  Looks like I have some housekeeping to do...